# Keras k_gather function

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Currently I'm trying to get the Keras backend function k_gather to work in R. Thus far no luck. I can only find proper documentation on the tensorflow gather function. If I follow this documentation the following piece of code should extract the (1,1,1)-entry of the tensor a.

```python
library(keras)

a =  k_constant(c(1L, 2L,3L,4L), dtype = 'int32' , shape = c(1L, 1L, 4L ))
c = k_constant(c(1L, 0L,0L,0L), dtype = 'int32' , shape = c(1L, 1L, 4L ))
out = k_gather(a , indices =  c )
sess$run(out)
```

However it doesn't seem to work that way. When I run it I get the error

```python
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,0,0] = 1 is not in [0, 1)
```

An error does not supprise me as the shape of out seems to be

```python
shape=(1, 1, 4, 1, 4)
```

instead of just

```python
 shape=(1, 1, 4)
```

How does it work. How can I extract the first component of my lovely tensor a?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not really useful, you should explain the problem thoroughly and include any error messages.

Comment: It would also be nice to state which language is that.... is it R?

Comment: Yes it's in R, but I would be able to translate a solution in Python back to R.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around this k_gather problem. I now use the following procedure to permute a tensor a

```
library(keras)

a =  k_constant(c(1L, 2L,3L,4L), dtype = 'int32' , shape = c(1L, 1L, 4L ))

a_1 =  a[,,1:2]
a_2 =  a[,,3:4]

a_new = k_concatenate( list(a_2, a_1))

sess = k_get_session()

sess$run(a_new)
```

It does not solve my issue with k_gather, but it does what I want.